# Representing LED colours with CSS

Tags: css, colors

I'm trying to represent the colour displayed on an LED with CSS. Obviously it's easy to use the background property with `RGBa`, however obviously black cannot be represented with LEDs.

Let's use red as an example:

For an LED, at full brightness, the LED will display red. However as the value decreases from 255 down to 0, it is similar to the transparency decreasing.

So the representation of `RGB(0, 0, 0)` should be a transparent background, rather than black. However, I'm not entirely sure how to work this out?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the `rgba` then, and decrease the alpha component ?

for full brightness

```
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
```

and when off

```
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0);
```

the alpha can vary between `0` and `1`

Comment: However that doesn't work when colour mixing for all three colours at the same time because you can't individually control the opacity (can you?)

Comment: @cheechm not sure what you mean. You can set the opacity to whatever. If using animations/transition you can alter the opacity between two keyframes with just the opacity changing..

Comment: But you can't set the opacity individually for each colour. All three colours at 0 should be represented by transparent,.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about simulating an LED that has a red, green and blue component inside of it and that you can't control all 3 with alpha because there is only one alpha channel for the 3 color components.

You can simulate the correct behavior though luckily.

Let's say the red component of the background color is 0.2.  That means for your LEDs red component, you have to map it's 0-1 value to 0-0.8 and add that to the 0.2 of the background color.  That will make it so when the red component is off, red will be 0.2 and when it's fully on, red will be 1.0.

Repeat this for green and blue and you'll have your resulting RGB color and not need to use alpha.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand. If the red LED were to be off, then the red colour component would be zero, which in CSS RGB terms would represent 00 in hex, however, given for an LED it would be off, that would represent an alpha of 0.

Comment: When the red LED is off, you'd have as much red as the background has. Turning on the red LED would just add more red to what is already there (capping it at 1.0, or full red). Repeat that for green and blue and you have a tricolor led setup

Comment: My problem is when there is no colour - that is represented by black if using RGB with background-color, however with an LED it should be represented as "transparent".